# How to make hibernate query( which are used for same purpose) generic?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Currently I am working on Spring Boot + Hibernate and I mostly end up writing repetitive hibernate query every time which are doing same kinda job, only difference is that the entity class different.

Example: here, I am retrieving a list from three different tables improvement_area, development_area and suggested_area. Below are the respective model class.

```
     public List<ImprovementArea> getImprovementAreaList(MainPlanSheet planSheet) {

    return HibernateUtils.getSession(sessionFactory)
                    .createCriteria(ImprovementArea.class).add(Restrictions.eq("planSheet", planSheet))
                    .list();
      }

public List<DevelopmentArea> getDevlopmentAreaList(MainPlanSheet planSheet) {

    return HibernateUtils.getSession(sessionFactory)
                     .createCriteria(DevelopmentArea.class).add(Restrictions.eq("planSheet", planSheet))
                    .list();
      }

public List<SuggestedArea> getSelectedSuggestedGoal(MainPlanSheet planSheet) {
    
    return HibernateUtils.getSession(sessionFactory)
            .createCriteria(SuggestedArea.class).add(Restrictions.eq("planSheet", planSheet))
            .list();
      }
```

as you could see all the three query is doing the same job, retrieving data from the respective model class.

Can someone please help me or suggest a better approach to make it generic?

Now another query added which accept Integer as parameter:

```
    public List<OnBoardedEmployee> getOnBoardedEmployees(Integer empId) {

    return HibernateUtils.getSession(sessionFactory)
            .createCriteria(OnBoardedEmployee.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("emId", empId))
            .list();
}
```

In this scenario how can I make one generic Instead of four different query?

Comment: Well as you already using Spring then maybe you should use Spring Data JPA for your persistence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply pass the class as an argument:

```
public <T> List<T> getDevlopmentByEntity(MainPlanSheet planSheet, Class<T> entity) {
    return HibernateUtils.getSession(sessionFactory)
        .createCriteria(entity)
        .add(Restrictions.eq("planSheet", planSheet))
        .list();
}
```

And invoke it like:

```
List<DevelopmentArea> developmentAreas = getSelectedSuggestedGoal(planSheet, DevelopmentArea.class);
```

Edit: the last snippet can be rewritten as:

```
public <T> List<T> getDevlopmentByEntity(String param, Object value, Class<T> entity) {
    return HibernateUtils.getSession(sessionFactory)
        .createCriteria(entity)
        .add(Restrictions.eq(param, value))
        .list();
}
```

Comment: Oh that's nice. Thank you. I have one doubt if the parameter got changed, like instead of `planSheet`, if I pass something else like Integer or String. What change I need to do here?

Comment: @Tech_sharma Yes, just introduce another parameter, like `String param` and place it as the first argument of the `eq` function. If this answer was helpful consider upvoting & accepting;>

Comment: you got me Wrong @Andronicus. I was asking to make the method parameter generic too. Like if I have another query:
`public List<OnBoardedEmployee> getOnBoardedEmployees(Integer empId) {

        return HibernateUtils.getSession(sessionFactory)
                .createCriteria(OnBoardedEmployee.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("emId", empId))
                .list();
    }`
Here the method parameter id Integer and other three method parameter was Model class Type. In this case, can I make the parameter generic?

Comment: @Tech_sharma you mean extracting `Restrictions.eq("planSheet", planSheet)`? Yeah, that also can be parameterized

Comment: @Tech_sharma that's what I meant, take a look at my edit